# Text string returned by request won't ast.literal_eval to list

Tags: python, python-requests, abstract-syntax-tree

Calling an API with requests to look up the description of a code. API returns string that looks like list. I am having trouble converting the string to a list with ast.literal_eval. I have tried many variations on response type (.text, .raw, etc.) and variations of map, str, etc. to convert the string. Would like to get the response into any usable Python object.

```
import requests
import ast

burl = "https://clinicaltables.nlm.nih.gov/" \
"api/icd10cm/v3/search?sf=code,name&maxList=1&terms="

dotted_code = "W59.21XS"

r = requests.get(burl+dotted_code).text

print(r)
```

response is:
[1,["W59.21XS"],null,[["W59.21XS","Bitten by turtle, sequela"]]]

but if I add:

```
l = ast.literal_eval(r)
print(l)
```

I get:

File "D:\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\ast.py", line 55, in _convert_num
    raise ValueError('malformed node or string: ' + repr(node))

ValueError: malformed node or string: <_ast.Name object at 0x0000015A01B670B8>

Any better way to get the return text into a usable Python object?

Comment: It's not a Python literal, that's why; it's JSON. Requests will handle it for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason *why* `literal_eval` does not work is becuase `null` does not exist in Python so `literal_eval` has no idea what to do with it. If you were to change `null` to `None` (or to the string `'null'`) then `literal_eval` would have worked:

```
>>> literal_eval('''[1,["W59.21XS"], None, [["W59.21XS","Bitten by turtle, sequela"]]]''')
[1, ['W59.21XS'], None, [['W59.21XS', 'Bitten by turtle, sequela']]]
```

You can use `response.json`:

```
>>> r = requests.get('https://clinicaltables.nlm.nih.gov/api/icd10cm/v3/search?sf=code,name&maxList=1&terms=W59.21XS')
>>> r.json()
[1, ['W59.21XS'], None, [['W59.21XS', 'Bitten by turtle, sequela']]]
#                 ^ Note that null was automatically converted to None
```

Answer (score 4):

That's JSON:

```
>>> import json
>>> json.loads("""[1,["W59.21XS"],null,[["W59.21XS","Bitten by turtle, sequela"]]]""")
[1, ['W59.21XS'], None, [['W59.21XS', 'Bitten by turtle, sequela']]]
```

Comment: No need to `import json`, just do `request.get(...).json()`

Comment: Using requests json() method is actually preferable since it does a better job of figuring out the type of encoding used compared to json.loads. Always use request's json method when downloading and converting json data.